# DRM Framework implementation error

Tags: java, android, drm, android-drm

I am developing an `ebook reader` as an android app. But I want the downloaded ebook files (eg. epub) to be DRM protected. I referred to the links mentioned below and tried to implement it but resulted with an error. I am at very beginning level of implementing DRM.

**My Code:**

```
    DrmManagerClient drmManagerClient = new DrmManagerClient(getApplicationContext());
    DrmInfoRequest drmInfoRequest = new DrmInfoRequest(0, "text/plain"); //<--- Error in this line
    DrmInfo drmInfo = drmManagerClient.acquireDrmInfo(drmInfoRequest);
    Log.e("sth...: ", drmInfo.getInfoType() + "");
```

**Error:**

> java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity
>   ComponentInfo{com.example.user.androiddrm/com.example.user.androiddrm.MainActivity}:
>   java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: infoType: 0,mimeType: text/plain

The basic code above is implemented based on the following documentation:

1. https://developer.android.com/reference/android/drm/package-summary.html
2. https://developer.android.com/reference/android/drm/DrmManagerClient.html#acquireDrmInfo(android.drm.DrmInfoRequest)
3. https://developer.android.com/reference/android/drm/DrmInfoRequest.html
4. https://source.android.com/devices/drm#DrmInfo

Now the **Link 4** explains about drm but using `MediaPlayer` as example but mine is for epub files. Even though the implementation of `acquireDrmInfo()` is different as followed to the above 3 links.

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44022453/how-to-use-android-drm-framework) link specifically targets for media player `Exoplayer`, so not much of help.

**Note:** After the epub file is downloaded, the user should be able to read offline so I don't think there will be any online activity.

So how to fix above error and is there any better tutorials on using Android.Drm Framework?

Comment: I would like to request the viewer of this question to UPVOTE this question since it might reach to the people who are expert in it. Thankyou

Comment: are you still trying to solve your react-native DRM issue (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47960233/how-do-i-implement-drm-on-react-native) and bridge the native Java code, or are you reverting to java completely for your application?